# Matlab matrix cropping of clusters

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

Given a matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

notice how the 1's are mainly clustered except for the 1 in the 3rd row, last column

what I want to do is get rid of excess 0's and keep only the cluster of 1's. This is what I'm trying to do with an image, so the cropped result should be rectangular:

```
0 1 1 1 
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0
```

the above crop is the smallest rectangular crop I can do to cover the most amount of 1's.

The problem I have right now is how do to this in matlab? I can't simply strip all 0's and I have to watch out for outlier 1's. What is the most efficient method to tackle this problem?

I can only think of manually going row by row, column by column to look for clusters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is equivalent to labeling 2D connected components in a binary image.  If you have access to the image processing toolbox, the function is `bwlabel`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwlabel.html

If you don't have acccess to `bwlabel`, there are several algorithms out there.  The fastest one I know of is the one that OpenCV uses, which finds closed contours in the image and is based on

F. Chang, C.-J. Chen, and C.-J. Lu, “A linear-time component-labeling
algorithm using contour tracing technique,” Computer Vision and Image
Understanding, vol. 93, no. 2, pp. 206–220, 2004

Comment: haha thanks, I just found out about bwlabel as well.But what if I have 2 clusters that are very close by? Is there a built in function to determine if the clusters determined in bwlabel have nearby neighbors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  As long as the clusters are separated by zeros, then they're returned as separate components.  If you want to "blur" components, then the best thing to do is probably do some image processing beforehand.  E.g., if you want blobs that are not more than 2 pixels apart to be treated as one, then dilate the image by 2 pixels.  If you want to separate overlapping blobs, then you're into a whole new can of worms :) (One that is near and dear to my heart, btw)

Comment: I'm dealing with saliency maps here and the binary matrix here determines which part of the original image is salient. For saliency maps there are often clusters of the image marked as salient, these clusters can be noticeably far away from one another and yet should still be part of the same cluster. Since I SIFT these images afterwards, I can't do any sort of processing.

Comment: Can't you do processing on the binary image (or a copy of it) and then discard it?  Another option is to subsample the binary image - i.e., if the clusters can be 1 pixel apart then use bwlabel(B([1 : 2 : end],[1 : 2 : end])), separated be 2 pixels do [1 : 3 : end], etc.  This is by far the fastest way, but it doesn't work except for powers of 2 and you have to be careful how you transform back to original coordinates.

Comment: haha I was writing out some pretty complex function that calculated centroid distances between clusters. Now that I think about it, with blurring the position of the salient object in the image is not changed. I need pretty intense pixel blurring though, maybe like 10 pixels apart. I don know how CPU intensive this is, compared to other methods, but it's definitely the easiest. What type of fspecial filter should I apply?

Comment: I would do something like `imdilate(I, strel('disk', 21))` (10 pixel radius).

Comment: the subsampling is great too, I will probably be going with that ultimately, since I value the performance of the code. All I need to do is get the dimension and range of the pixels so I can pinpoint it from the orig image. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that will be the fastest.  Be careful, though: you're counting on that pixel that you're sampling belonging to a blob.  Pathological case: every pixel in the image is 1 except the pixels that you sample -> looks like no blobs! I'm sure you could put some stochastic limits on the performance you get.   PS: Answer credit would be a nice way to say thanks :)

Comment: yea, since I'm dealing with somewhat large images, a blob that gets missed because of a few pixel jumps doesn't deserve to be a blob.